# Restrict Alphabets using keypress function javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to restrict alphabets in javascript. Here is the code I am using and I am able to show alert to users "Enter numbers only" if they enter alphabets.

But issue is after entering values in the textbox, if I try to backspace the values, it shows alert("Enter numbers only"

How to not show alert if I press backspace key.

Here is my code,

```
       PasswordCheck(event)  
        {
              var allowedRegex =  /^[0-9]+$/ && event.keyCode === 8;     
              if (!event.key.match(allowedRegex)) {
              alert("Enter Numbers only")
              event.preventDefault();
        }

       
         <form (keyup)="PasscodeCheck($event)" autocomplete="off">
         ......
         </form>
```

Comment: Isn't `keyCode` deprecated?

Comment: Can't you just use an input box with type text?

Answer (score 1):

```
 PasswordCheck(event) {
    var allowedRegex =  /^[0-9]+$/;     
    if (!event.key.match(allowedRegex) && event.keyCode !== 8) {
      alert("Enter Numbers only");
    }
  }
```